# How can I compute the distance between two actors in Stencyl?

Tags: stencyl

How do U use the "distance" behavior in Stencyl?

I need to know the distance between two actors in order to start a timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [Custom Block](http://www.stencyl.com/help/viewArticle/106/). With the custom block you can make your own logic, and lucky for you, the page even provides distance between actors (X distance anyway) as the example:

[image]

Remember the documentation is always an excellent place to start with questions like this, and Stencyl appears to have [great documentation.](http://www.stencyl.com/help/)

Comment: Great!! Thanks, you saved my LD Jam :P (Lesson leared ... check the documentation first :P )